# Invalid regex check in BASH match

Tags: regex, bash

I am looking for a regexp match for `-h` and `--help` thought the below should match it does not behave the way that i expect, what am i doing wrong?

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^((-{1,2})([Hh]$|[Hh][Ee][Ll][Pp])|)$ ]] ; then
  echo 'help flagged' ; exit 0
fi
```

please keep in mind that getop IS used farther down in the code...

Expected results are if either -h or --help (any case) are hit we echo and exit

Comment: `shopt -s nocasematch; [[ $1 = @(-h|--help) ]]` seems a lot simpler. Your code would match `-help` and `--h` as well (which maybe is intentional).

Comment: It also looks like it will match `-` and `--`, due to the last pipe character.

Comment: `@(..|..)` needs extglob on in case that isn't already enabled.

Comment: `extglob` just enables extended patterns for pathname generation (aka globbing); extended patterns are always available inside `[[ ... ]]` for pattern matching on strings.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, wonderful points and answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to match is either `-h` or `--help`, regardless of case, I would use

```
if (shopt -s nocasematch; [[ $1 = @(-h|--help) ]]); then
```

The subshell isolates the change in the `casematch` option to this test, and the extended pattern matches either `-h` or `--help`. (It's shorter than `[[ $1 = -h || $1 = --help ]]`.)